# if the json is duplicate, return the first element

Tags: json, reactjs, duplicates

I'm not sure if there is already a function for this, what I need is the following
a json in reactjs, and I need this to search if the cities are repeated and return only one result,
example if I have 5 berlin, only the first berlin returns
If I have 5 california, the first california returns

```
[
    {id:1, city: "berlin"},
    {id:2, city: "berlin"},
    {id:3, city: "berlin"},
    {id:5, city: "california"},
    {id:6, city: "california"},
    {id:7, city: "california"}
]
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the results using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to check for duplicates:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"city":"berlin"},{"id":2,"city":"berlin"},{"id":3,"city":"berlin"},{"id":5,"city":"california"},{"id":6,"city":"california"},{"id":7,"city":"california"}];

const result = arr.filter(function({ city }) {
  return this.has(city) ? false : this.add(city);
}, new Set);

console.log(result);
```

Or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by country, and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) back to array:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"city":"berlin"},{"id":2,"city":"berlin"},{"id":3,"city":"berlin"},{"id":5,"city":"california"},{"id":6,"city":"california"},{"id":7,"city":"california"}];

const result = [...arr.reduce((m, o) => m.has(o.city) ? m : m.set(o.city, o), new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, great, with the first example i could resolve, thanks

Comment: @Markapp - enjoy :)